# undefined arrays problem in merge sort visualizer in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript

I'm trying to make a sorting algorithm visualizer using Angular. Currently doing merge sort and its giving me troubles. I am a Java programmer so I think there is something I'm doing wrong with the typescript with the recursive calls. When I run the program it is giving me errors saying 'cannot read property length of undefined'. I am lost and can't seem to put a finger on where I am going wrong.

In my first function I repeatedly split the original array called visualArr which is a global array in my program sized by the user and used for the visualization of the sorting algorithms. Then the second function I have is used for the merging of the split arrays.

```
  performMergeSort(arr) {
    if (arr.length <= 1) {
      return arr;
    }

    const middle = Math.floor(arr.length / 2);

    let left = arr.slice(0, middle);
    let right = arr.slice(middle, arr.length);

    left = this.performMergeSort(left);
    right = this.performMergeSort(right);

    return this.performMerge(left, right);
  }
```

The timer function in the second code block is used for visuals of the sort. However, I think there is something wrong with either my logic or something I am doing wrong in TypeScript. Any feedback is appreciated.

```
performMerge(leftArr, rightArr) {
    let lIdx = 0;
    let rIdx = 0;
    let i = 0;

    timer(0, 100)
    .pipe(takeWhile(() => leftArr.length > lIdx && rightArr.length > rIdx))
    .subscribe(() => {
      const lItem = leftArr[lIdx];
      const rItem = rightArr[rIdx];

      if (lItem > rItem) {
        this.visualArr[i] = rItem;
        rIdx++;
      } else {
        this.visualArr[i] = lItem;
        lIdx++;
      }
      i++;
    });

    timer(0, 100)
    .pipe(takeWhile(() => leftArr.length > lIdx ))
    .subscribe(() => {
      this.visualArr[lIdx] = leftArr[lIdx++];
    });

    timer(0, 100)
    .pipe(takeWhile(() => rightArr.length > rIdx ))
    .subscribe(() => {
      this.visualArr[rIdx] = rightArr[rIdx++];
    });
  }
```

Comment: How have to declared your array?

Answer (score 0):

This error normally comes when you haven't initialized array correctly.
Try this:-

```
visualArr:number[]=[];
```

Comment: @DemirM123 does this answer your question? If yes then accept the answer and close this question.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you cannot read the property length  of an array if it is not defined, i.e. it is not initialized, so try to initialize all your arrays:

if you know the type: `myArray:string[]=[]`

if not just do this: `myArray=[]`